# nodemailer google smtp connection closed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email

I am trying to send email using nodemailer and nodemailer-smtp-transport in express js. i am creating a custom module to send mails to the user. When ever i am executing the script it is throwing 2 specific errors.

**Error 1**

```
D:\Projects\project_name\modules\mailer.js:45
                        throw error;
                        ^

Error: Connection closed

at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\WISSENX\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\lib\smtp-transport.js:113:29)
at SMTPConnection.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:166:7)
at SMTPConnection._destroy (D:\Projects\WISSENX\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:558:10)
at SMTPConnection._onEnd (D:\Projects\WISSENX\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:538:10)
at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

**Error 2**

```
{
[Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.gmail.com smtp.gmail.com:465]

code: 'ECONNECTION',

errno: 'ENOTFOUND',

syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',

host: 'smtp.gmail.com',

port: '465',

command: 'CONN' }
```

My Complete code is

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport")

var constants = require('./../modules/constants');


/*var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(constants.MAIL_HOST,{
 service : "Gmail",
     auth: {
        user: constants.MAIL_FROM_AUTH,
        pass: constants.MAIL_PASSWORD
    }
});*/


var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host : constants.MAIL_HOST,
    secureConnection : constants.MAIL_SECURE,
    port: constants.MAIL_PORT,
    auth : {
        user : constants.MAIL_FROM_AUTH,
        pass : constants.MAIL_PASSWORD
    },
    ignoreTLS: true
}));



var sendMail = function(req, res, template, to, subject, callback) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: constants.MAIL_FROM, // sender address
        to: to, // list of receivers
        subject: subject, // Subject line
        text: "random text", // plaintext body
        html: template // html body
    }
console.log(mailOptions);
console.log(smtpTransport);

    // send mail with defined transport object
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
console.log("Message sent: " + response);
console.log(error);
        if(error) {
            throw error;
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        }

        smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages

    });
}
exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

Comment: What is your `MAIL_HOST`?

Comment: For well-known services  as Gmail you can use `service: 'gmail'` in config object in smtpTransport https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer-smtp-transport#using-well-known-services

Comment: "MAIL_HOST" is constant i was using. i solved the issue, issue was with port number for non SSL.